# new command generate additional space if use "\relax"

Tags: latex

I find that `\newcommand` with `\relax` will generate additional space, e.g. in the following code, I tested two custom cmd, one is `\relax`, another is `\marginpar`, the code and results are as follows.

I expect they should have same result, in sentence 2, I added one `\relax`, it's still same with line 1. But in line 3, if I use my custom command with same functionality, there will be an unexpected space. I have to remove one space between command and text (sentence 4 or sentence 5).

As comparison, I changed `\relax` to `\marginpar` (it's like another "relax" command since in text it do nothing but just add text to sidebar). It performs as expected.

Is it feature of latex or is it problem of `\newcommand` with relax? How should I change the command, so that it could give same result like `\marginpar`?

I tested like `\ignorespaces`, but it still doesn't give identical result.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\testcmdMarginPar}[1]{\marginpar{#1}}

\newcommand{\testcmd}[1]{\relax}


\begin{document}



sdfsdfds    this is a test

sdfsdfds \relax this is a test

sdfsdfds \testcmd{abc} this is a test

sdfsdfds \testcmd{abc}this is a test

sdfsdfds\testcmd{abc} this is a test






-----------------------------------

sdfsdfds\testcmdMarginPar{abc} this is a test

sdfsdfds \testcmdMarginPar{abc} this is a test

sdfsdfds \testcmdMarginPar{abc} this is a test

sdfsdfds    this is a test



\end{document}
```

the result:

> sdfsdfds this is a test
>
> sdfsdfds this is a test
>
> sdfsdfds    this is a test
>
> sdfsdfds this is a test
>
> sdfsdfds this is a test
>
> ———————————–
>
> sdfsdfds this is a test abc
>
> sdfsdfds this is a test abc
>
> sdfsdfds this is a test abc
>
> sdfsdfds this is a test

[image: result link]